# Openshift + Jenkins Cannot Allocate Memory During Build

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, openshift

I'm using `Gradle` + `Jenkins` on Openshift to build and deploy a java (diy) app. Prior to deployment the app is made into a **fat jar** (via the [shadow gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow)). During this bundling phase the following error is thrown: `java.io.IOException`: Cannot allocate memory.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a larger gear size for your jenkins instance so that you don't run out of memory, you can also try increasing the amount of your gears memory that can be used for the JVM like this : https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbosseap-jvm-memory.html

That is for JBoss EAP, but it should also work for Jenkins (you may have to restart your jenkins gear after you run the command)